# Link to applied_count leads to a 404

Tags: bug, tags, documentation, api-v2.1

## To Reproduce

[Run an API query on tag-synonyms](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tag-synonyms#order=desc&sort=creation&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true), you will get a result that includes something like this:

[image: applied_count link]

## Issue(s)

Click on the `applied_count` link and you get redirected to [this page](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/applied_count) which is a 404.

It isn't quite clear what `applied_count` is anyway. The docs don't explain it, and on the main site [synonym page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?tab=newest&filter=all) it is called 'Renames'. Any chance that could be fixed while you're at it?

Comment: Confirmed.  This is a bug of [the doc pages](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tag-synonyms) that adds that bogus hyperlink.  [The actual API results](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/tags/synonyms?order=desc&sort=creation&site=stackoverflow) do not have it.